# Spring Batch : Remove stack trace of run time exception from exit description

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In my Spring Batch Job if there is an unhandled exception in step ItemWriter (for ex Primary Key Violation because of bad data while saving to DB), my job fails and then I get another error because core spring batch is not able to update the failed exit status to BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table. The Reason Being that the exit Description has full stack trace which is larger than the size of db column (2500).

How should I handle these exceptions in spring batch? How can I trim this exit description to smaller custom message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I handle these exceptions in spring batch?

I would fix the root cause by validating data to be conform to the db schema (the right type, the right length, etc) before writing it. [Data validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#validatingInput) is a typical use case for an item processor.

> How can I trim this exit description to smaller custom message?

Instead of trimming the stack trace (this would make it unreadable and hence you will not be able to see the root cause of the exception which is at the end of the stack trace), you can enlarge the column length using [maxVarcharLength](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/JobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#setMaxVarCharLength-int-).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Sybase DB. Would it be ok to just change the underlying column type to "text" to store large data.

Comment: I checked a typical Stacktrace is 5000 char length and max size of varchar in sybase is 8000. I was thinking of having the stacktrace in logs and have a custom message in database exit description. A developer could miss the data validation or there could be an unexpected run time exception and i am trying to figure out a way that in such a scenario core spring batch DB Update still succeeds

Comment: yes, you might need to extend the column size as well. If there is a db exception, Spring Batch can't force it to succeed.